# How to activate specific movie clip within a container mc added from as3 class

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, animation, movieclip

I have an Enemy movie clip that has 3 other child movie clips inside on frame 1,2,and 3 (each with different animation), it is loaded from an .as Enemy class.  How do I make my hit test link to a specific movie clip inside the Enemy container movie clip? I have been able to activate events within the MC on frame 1, but don't seem to be able to get to the ones on frame 2 or 3.

I am using:

```
 this.instance_name.gotoAndPlay(2)
```

but the Enemy vanishes instead of changing to another animation. The enemies spawn of stage to the right, so I thought that is why it disappears, but no new animation comes in later, always the same first frame animation enemy. What I need is for the 2 animation MC to replace the first one in the exact same spot showing a reaction to hittest from bullet or the player. Don't know if it's a code thing or just movie clip placement or a class code thing.

Comment: Please, please format your question better.

Comment: Please show more code. Where is that line of code located?  Maybe `gotoAndPlay` is wrong. Do yo really want to *play* all frames after frame 2? Maybe it's just animating empty frames. `gotoAndStop` might help in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I would say its definitely the gotoAndPlay, unless you have stop(); situated in your timeline somewhere it will just cycle onwards through all the animations on the timeline instead of staying on frame 2 where you can see the correct animation.